# No Method Error on .each What am I missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to have my carousel and index rendered on the home page. I'm getting a no method error on my .each loop but I can't seem to track down the problem. Here is my code please help =/. Everything looks right to me as I am following a fairly recent tutorial.

Showing /Users/prestonphan/Desktop/My_Portfolio/app/views/posts/_index.html.erb where line #1 raised:

**posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

    def index  
        @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
    end

    def new
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)
        @post.save
        redirect_to @post
    end

    def show
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    private
    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
    end
end
```

**_index.html.erb**

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <div class="post_wrapper">
        <h2 class="title"><%= link_to post.title, post %></h2>
        <p class="date"><%= post.created_at.strftime['%B, %d, %Y']%></p>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**home.html.erb**

```
<div class="jumbotron center">
    <h1>Eggsix</h1>
    <p>dozens by the half</p>
</div>
<%= render 'static_pages/carousel'%>
<%= render 'posts/index'%>
```

https://github.com/Eggsix/Half_dozen_full

Comment: Try removing the `=` after `<%` on the first line of `index.html.erb`.

Comment: it's pointing to `_index.html.erb`

Comment: Post the full names of the files above, and the request controller and action. The posted "home" erb has a post/index partial. Are you going through the `index` action of the `posts_controller` ?

Comment: I posted the full names to the files above. I'm a total noob at rails, so im not sure how to request controller and action? I am going through the index of the posts_controller, when I but then when I removed the index as a partial I received a new error in the posts_controller @post = Post.find(params[:id]). Which works fine when submit a new blog it would show me what I inserted.

Comment: what is the url you are trying to access when you get this error?

Comment: It's considered good practice *not* to be using instance variables in your partials directly. You'd quickly lose track of which instance variables are used where. It's better to pass them in as locals: `<%= render 'posts/index', posts: @posts %>`. Then in the partial, this variable can be accessed easily: `<% posts.each do |post| %>`

Comment: how many posts do you have in your database? Use `if @posts.present?` before `@posts.each do |post|` so if there are no records in your database then it wont throw an error.

Comment: @AdityaShedge you are wrong. `.each` won't raise exception when called for empty array.

Comment: @rustam-a-gasanov yes it doesnt raise exception for empty array or ActiveRecord_Relation. But OP says 'I'm getting a no method error on my .each loop' which is why I asked him to check for `present?` The issue may be something else   . It was not a solution lol

Comment: @AdityaShedge an empty table in db will not raise any kind of errors when calling `.each`. I will just return `nil` wich in his case will not display anything on page/ This has nothing to do with the table being empty.

Comment: Seems like the request goes through the StaticPagesController and not the PostsController. StaticPagesController home action renders home.html.erb, which then renders posts/_index.html.erb partial. '@posts' is not set by StaticPagesController and is therefore nil. Calling .each on nil will throw a NoMethodError. You probably need to set '@posts' in StaticPagesController home action.

Comment: I'll try the static_pages one that seems about right as well?

Comment: I ended up using the global variable which worked out really well. Is that an acceptable ruby convention?

Comment: @EggSix no, it is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to re-use some view, make a partial like this(it is more convenient to add partials like `_post.html.erb` to render a single item, but for your understanding I made solution simplier):

**app/views/posts/_posts.html.erb**

```
<% posts.each do |post| %>
  <div class="post_wrapper">
    <h2 class="title"><%= link_to post.title, post %></h2>
    <p class="date"><%= post.created_at.strftime['%B, %d, %Y']%></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Then, in **app/views/posts/index.html.erb** just call partial render, providing a collection of posts:

```
<%= render partial: 'posts/posts', locals: { posts: @posts } %>
```

Same for **app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb**, add:

```
<%= render partial: 'posts/posts', locals: { posts: @posts } %>
```

But your `@posts` variable is `nil` for `home` view case, so you should fetch posts in `home` action of your `StaticPagesController` too:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
  end
end
```

Thats it. Hope this makes sense to you.

Comment: Thank you so much, this answers everything! More importantly provided a better understanding this makes a lot more sense